# Update Doctrine entity's property with value from another entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5, easyadmin

I'm trying to update an entity in my database, with a field which should hold the currently logged in userID, but I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Book::setIsBorrowedBy() must be an instance of App\Entity\User or null, int given

Since I'm new to the topic I would appreciate any help.

I'm calling `MediaCrudController::updateEntity`, where the method setting the field is `Book::setIsBorrowedBy`. It should get the current (integer) UserID.

Thanks a lot.

**book.php** (entity)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\MediaRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MediaRepository::class)
 */
class Book
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $coverPicture;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date_immutable")
     */
    private $dateOfPublication;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isBorrowedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isConfirmed = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Genre::class, inversedBy="books")
     */
    private $genre;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class, inversedBy="books")
     */
    private $isBorrowedBy;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $isRequested;

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCoverPicture(): ?string
    {
        return $this->coverPicture;
    }

    public function setCoverPicture(?string $coverPicture): self
    {
        $this->coverPicture = $coverPicture;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDateOfPublication(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->dateOfPublication;
    }

    public function setDateOfPublication(\DateTimeImmutable $dateOfPublication): self
    {
        $this->dateOfPublication = $dateOfPublication;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAuthor(): ?string
    {
        return $this->author;
    }

    public function setAuthor(string $author): self
    {
        $this->author = $author;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsBorrowed(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isBorrowed;
    }

    public function setIsBorrowed(?bool $isBorrowed): self
    {
        $this->isBorrowed = $isBorrowed;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsBorrowedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->isBorrowedAt;
    }

    public function setIsBorrowedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $isBorrowedAt): self
    {
        $this->isBorrowedAt = $isBorrowedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsConfirmed(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isConfirmed;
    }

    public function setIsConfirmed(?bool $isConfirmed): self
    {
        $this->isConfirmed = $isConfirmed;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGenre(): ?Genre
    {
        return $this->genre;
    }

    public function setGenre(?Genre $genre): self
    {
        $this->genre = $genre;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsBorrowedBy(): ?User
    {
        return $this->isBorrowedBy;
    }

    public function setIsBorrowedBy(?User $isBorrowedBy): self
    {
        $this->isBorrowedBy = $isBorrowedBy;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsRequested(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isRequested;
    }

    public function setIsRequested(?bool $isRequested): self
    {
        $this->isRequested = $isRequested;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**user.php** (entity)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = ["ROLE_USER"];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $birthdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $adress;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isEnabled = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Book::class, mappedBy="isBorrowedBy")
     */
    private $books;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUserIdentifier(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @deprecated since Symfony 5.3, use getUserIdentifier instead
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    public function getRoles(): ?array
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Returning a salt is only needed, if you are not using a modern
     * hashing algorithm (e.g. bcrypt or sodium) in your security.yaml.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt(): ?string
    {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function getFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstname;
    }

    public function setFirstname(string $firstname): self
    {
        $this->firstname = $firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(string $surname): self
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBirthdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->birthdate;
    }

    public function setBirthdate(\DateTimeInterface $birthdate): self
    {
        $this->birthdate = $birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAdress(): ?string
    {
        return $this->adress;
    }

    public function setAdress(string $adress): self
    {
        $this->adress = $adress;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsEnabled(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isEnabled;
    }

    public function setIsEnabled(bool $isEnabled): self
    {
        $this->isEnabled = $isEnabled;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Book[]
     */
    public function getBooks(): Collection
    {
        return $this->books;
    }

    public function addBook(Book $book): self
    {
        if (!$this->books->contains($book)) {
            $this->books[] = $book;
            $book->setIsBorrowedBy($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeBook(Book $book): self
    {
        if ($this->books->removeElement($book)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($book->getIsBorrowedBy() === $this) {
                $book->setIsBorrowedBy(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**controller.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Media;

use App\Entity\Book;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FieldCollection;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Collection\FilterCollection;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Actions;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Crud;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Filters;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\EntityDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Dto\SearchDto;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\DateField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Filter\EntityFilter;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Orm\EntityRepository;
class MediaCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Book::class;
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Available Mediatheque Item')
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Available Mediatheque Items')
            ->setSearchFields(['title', 'author', 'genre.type'])
            ->setDefaultSort(['dateOfPublication' => 'ASC'])
            ->showEntityActionsInlined();

    }

    public function configureFilters(Filters $filters): Filters
    {
        return $filters
            ->add(EntityFilter::new('genre')->setLabel('Genre'));
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        yield TextField::new('title')->hideOnForm();
        yield TextField::new('author')->hideOnForm();
        yield TextField::new('coverPicture')->hideOnForm();
        yield AssociationField::new('genre')->hideOnForm();
        yield DateField::new('dateOfPublication')->hideOnForm();
        yield BooleanField::new('isRequested')->onlyOnForms()
            ->setLabel('Make a Borrow Request')
            ->setHelp('If you want to borrow this Item, please flip the switch and save your Request');
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {

        return $actions
            ->setPermission(Action::NEW, 'ROLE_EDITOR')
            ->setPermission(Action::DELETE, 'ROLE_EDITOR')
            ->setPermission(Action::DETAIL, 'ROLE_EDITOR')
            ->setPermission(Action::EDIT, 'ROLE_USER')
            ->setPermission(Action::BATCH_DELETE, 'ROLE_EDITOR')
            ->update(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::EDIT, function (Action $action)
            {
                return $action->setLabel('Borrow')->setIcon('fa fa-star');
            });
    }

    public function createIndexQueryBuilder(SearchDto $searchDto, EntityDto $entityDto, FieldCollection $fields, FilterCollection $filters): QueryBuilder
    {
        $qb = $this->get(EntityRepository::class)->createQueryBuilder($searchDto, $entityDto, $fields, $filters);
        $qb->andWhere('entity.isBorrowedBy IS NULL');

        return $qb;
    }

    public function updateEntity(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, $entityInstance): void
    {
        $entityInstance->setIsBorrowedAt(new \DateTime());
        $entityInstance->setIsBorrowedBy($this->getUser()->getId());
      parent::updateEntity($entityManager, $entityInstance);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your book entity says:

```php
public function setIsBorrowedBy(?User $isBorrowedBy): self
```

but in MediaCrudController::updateEntity you pass the userId instead of the user object:

```php
$entityInstance->setIsBorrowedBy($this->getUser()->getId());
```

Maybe that's the problem?

---

Remember that in cases where you don't have the object itself, you can retrieve it with Doctrine like this:

```
$userObject = $this->doctrine->getManager()->getRepository(User::class)->find($this->getUser()->getId());
```